# You must create this type of ParseObject using ParseObject.create() or the proper subclass. - crashed app but code is correct

Tags: android, parse-platform, authentication

When i'm trying to log in error appears and aplication is closing.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must create this type of ParseObject using ParseObject.create() or the proper subclass.

This is communicate and its showing me that ParseUser user = new ParseUser(); is wrong but its not.

```
public class RegisterScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edUsernameReg,edPasswordReg;
    Button registerBtn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_screen);

        edUsernameReg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edUsernameReg);
        edPasswordReg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edPasswordReg);
        registerBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);

        registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String username = edUsernameReg.getText().toString();
                String password = edPasswordReg.getText().toString();

                ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                user.setUsername(username);
                user.setPassword(password);
                user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if(e == null){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Parse signup error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfully registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterScreen.this,LoginScreen.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I was looking for tutorials but all of them are based exactly on documentation so am i. Please help.

Comment: With Parse shutting down, is it possible the docs are out of date? Have you tried replacing new ParseUser() with ParseUser.create()?

Comment: There is no such a thing... i guess documentation is not fresh. I don't see even fresh tutorials on the internet so i think parse.com is going down slowly. Maybe there is something similar to parse.com but working?

Comment: Check if you have initialized Parse in your Application file. If you have, check your AndroidManifest.xml if name attribute has been set to your Application file in the application tag.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added

```xml
<application
   android:name=".App"
   ...>
   ...
</application>
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml file.
Here App is the class where the API keys are/the class that initializes Parse

Answer (score 0):

The most people do mistake including me is ***Make sure on every launch your code don't skip the*** `Parse.initialize()` call. Parse initialize register your classes every time you launch app. **Register your subclasses before calling** `Parse.initialize()`

You can check if user is already logged in before calling logInInBackground().

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    if(currentUser!=null){
       // user is already logged in, do what you want
    }
    else{
        showLoginUI();
    }
```